# Is it possible to have multiple containers have different effects on word wrapping?

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I have a container that holds a container that holds text such as

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the inner container is centered in the outer one and is smaller than it

```css
#inner {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Is it possible to implement a word wrap rule like this?

- If possible without breaking apart a word, break line inside the inner container
- If not possible, let the word reach beyond bound of inner container
- If the word reaches the outer container's bounds, break it apart regardless of spaces

Illustration:

```
┌───────────────────────────┐
│        ┌─────────┐        │
│        │A sentence        │
│        │that goes│        │
│        │over the bounds   │
│        │of the inner      │
│        │container│        │
│        │But if we│        │
│        │have a word       │
│        │that's far        │
│        │too long,│        │
│        │such as  │        │
│        │Antidisestablishme│
│        │ntarianism,       │
│        │it's broken       │
│        │apart.   │        │
│        └─────────┘        │
└───────────────────────────┘
```

I've tried doing it like this:

```css
#outer {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

#inner {
  overflow-wrap: normal;
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: By your own rules shouldn't "A" and "sentence" be on separate lines? I guess maybe you just want to limit it to 1 word being out of the inner bounds?

Comment: No. I want a word that *starts* left of the inner boundary and would end left of the outer boundary to break after it, not at it or before it

Comment: you can do this with js if you know the width of the inner container, using math to get characters allowed and then rebuilding your sentence by adding line breaks where needed as you loop through your original sentence

Comment: Is there a way to do it w/ CSS?

Comment: Is it important that the inner element is smaller? Couldn't you just make it right-aligned with a set width? That way it would line-break when it reaches the right bound of the outer container.

Comment: Yes, that's the entire point. I want the effect of it being in the center with a bit of leeway to the side but without it hiding text if the outer div is too small